# How are the parallel tracks for cross-country skiing created?

Tags: trivia, cross-country-skiing

How are the parallel tracks created for cross country skiing competitions? The tracks seem almost perfectly parallel and maintain a perfect shape even after the passage of many skiers - for example:

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: @PhilipKendall my English is not so fine and I'd like to receive any suggestions to make the questions more understandable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you’ve indicated, the tracks are typically perfect.  That’s because they are made with snow grooming equipment similar to the [Trakor](http://www.snowgroomers.net/htm/classic.htm).  It’s a device that is towed behind a snow machine or other vehicle while grooming the snow.   While it’s not terrible high tech, it lays a perfectly groomed track with the ability to adjust the trail widths.